# How Can I Remove Isotope All Filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for delete, remove, disable isotope all filter but I can't find any simple guide!

You can see my filters code:

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".webDesign">Web Designs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".webDevelop">Web Developments</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".graphicDesign">Graphic Designs</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Above I have data-filter="*" but I want to disable it! ( disable all item show )

I removed this line: `<li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>`

But isotope show all items and that's not working!

Anybody know how can I remove isotope all image show? I just need another filter!

---

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

Remove line:

```
<li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="active">All</a></li>
```

Initialize isotope by using a default filter:

```
$('#container').isotope({ filter: '.metal' });
```

Comment: hi thankyou for you answer ! i want to delete Filter named All ( data-filter="*" ) this filter shows all items. but i don't want to isotope show all items so i need to remove this filter. but i don't know how can i remove this filter

Comment: sorry for other question ! do you know how can i responsive ISOTOPE Image ? i add this simple code : img { height: auto; max-width: 100%; } and this code work on any images except isotope items ( images ).

Comment: You can open a new question for that :)